# Keeping uploaded images in tmpfolder for resizing

Tags: php, apache2, temp

I am working on an upload script that also resizes/rescales an image.

Currently it is working by uploading the image, moving to the upload dir (site.com/upload) and then resizing, and afterwards deleting the original again...

Now my question is:
Can I do this without moving the original to the upload dir and even better, also keeping the new file in tmp so I the user can afterwards confirm the image (so If they don't want it and just hit the 'back' button it won't stay in the upload dir.)

Current code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'resize-upload/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
$filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];    
$Imagick=new Imagick();
$Imagick-> readImage('resize-upload/'.$filename);
$Imagick-> scaleImage(200,200,auto);
$Imagick-> writeImage('resize-upload/resized-'.$filename);


unlink('resize-upload/'.$filename);
```

Comment: Why not resizing then overwriting the original itself?

Comment: True, just added the unlink quickly to test it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You don't have the access to the image if you haven't moved it yet. But you can generate more than one thumbnail at a time from same image/object and if you are storing/keeping the original also then you don't need to unlink it either.

Another way would be to use flash and resize the image on the client side and then only save the resized image.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that it was possible to access the image because it should be allready on the server... And flash isn't that much of an option since it's supposed to be a really simple and quick site :P, but thanks for this answer